# PHP mysqli_num_rows for each result in bar chart? CanvasJS AND PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, canvasjs

Here's what I am trying to do.

I have vendors that I purchase leads from, I need to view a comparison of all the billable leads in my system to see which vendors are performing and which are not. Q represents a billable lead. With my present code, I get my graph, it lists all vendors in the legend but the billable (Q) amount for each vendor is showing the amount total of all billable (Q) leads from all vendors on each vendor. I'm prety sure that I need to have my $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); somewhere inside   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    I just cant figure it out, I've read everything I can.. If anyone knows how to fix this please help. Thanks    I am using CanvasJS and PHP

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
 {
  title:{
    text: "Top Oil Reserves"    
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
  },
  legend: {
    verticalAlign: "bottom",
    horizontalAlign: "center"
  },
  theme: "theme1",
  data: [

   {        
    type: "column",  
    showInLegend: true, 
    legendMarkerColor: "grey",
    legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
    dataPoints: [    


<?php
   include 'include/dbconnect.php'; 


   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM EduCampaign1 WHERE leadstatus='Q'");


 $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {



     ?>  


      {y:<?php echo $rowcount; ?>, label: "<?php echo( htmlspecialchars($row['rid'] )   ); ?>"},

    <?php
        }
 mysqli_close($con); 
 ?> 




     ]
   }   
  ]
  });

chart.render();
}
</script>




<script src="lib/js/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

```
 <body>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code before your while statement: 
$c=0;

inside your while statement:
$c++;

What this does is make a simple row counter. Each time a record is passed the counter will go up.